# Need help configuring/setting up something with git (new)

Tags: git

I have never worked with git before, and Im confused as to where to enter the "install the server" part to get this working..

http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/

Details in steps would be very helpful! Thanks!!

Comment: I have no idea what that means..I expressed how I have never used git before and need detailed steps. I appreciate your help explaining this in more detail..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the terminal / console / cmd / command-line of your OS, it says so in the article:

> To install, simply run the following from the command-line/console:

This has nothing to do with git. This is how you enter commands and git is just another command.

Comment: Im using osx lion, where do i do this then? Im not familiar with this process, sorry.

Comment: @Reuben In OS X, just hit command + space and type terminal and enter. It opens terminal and you have to enter the commands there.

Comment: Ive tried that and entered:

git clone https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave-server.git
node chrome-devtools-autosave-server/index.js

I get this back:

-bash: git: command not found

Comment: Still confused..I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: @Reuben - You are on the right track there. You have to learn the basics of what you are trying to do here. Can't help you more...

Comment: @Reuben: You don't have `git` installed.  You need to download and install it first.  For Mac, see: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3

Comment: Thank you!! 

It seems they have changed how to set it up (I've installed node.js)..I am getting a different error now.. 

http://reubenpressman.com/error.txt

Sorry this is such a pain..

Comment: @Reuben - You will have to start a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If it says "command not found" then git is not installed on your Mac.

Install it from:  [Git Download Site](http://git-scm.com/)

and then try the instructions again.